# MySQL access takes longer to access from another PC on the same network as the sever

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I have setup MySQL server on my laptop. I have also created a simple application on a visual studio that connects to the server via a login page. Simple user and password.

It takes probably 2 seconds to connected to the database.

However, when I run the same application on a second PC on the same network, it takes about a minute to login. Is this delay due to a slow network?

And how do I resolve this delay?

```
private void button27_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("server=192.168.0.5;user id=user;database=dba;password=dthdhdjzjtdx132425432451xfbxfnxf"))
        {
            try
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    DataTable table = new DataTable();
                    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM new", connection);
                    adapter.Fill(table);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference between computers ? In term of Operating System, cables, firewall, motherboard, CPU, Network adapter, Wifi or RJ45, software, and so on ? If I undestand, it takes 2 seconds for local connection, and 1 mins for distant cennection, is it that ? It is strange for a local network...

Comment: 1 minute makes no sense. You should have gotten a timeout WAY before that. You have probably a firewall issue on your second computer delaying the request to get out.

Comment: Side note: you don't need the `if` the connection always starts closed after you instatiate it.

Comment: Exactly, this should be some kind of hardware or system problem. From a coding point of view there is nothing better that you can do

Comment: @OlivierRogier "If I undestand, it takes 2 seconds for local connection, and 1 mins for distant cennection, is it that ?" correct

Comment: How are you measuring time? Are you sure it's the connection that is taking that long and not other code that runs before the connection? It's the same database with the same amout of data?

Comment: @Franck Atfer your statement I timed it more accurately. The second computer takes 35seconds and the local PC takes 2 seconds.

Comment: @Magnetron basic stopwatch. Nothing in the backgorund. That code start after the button is clicked

Comment: @David Wifi or RJ45 ? What OS and what .NET platform and version on each computers ?

Comment: @OlivierRogier WIFI, WINDOWS AND 4.7.2. Version on local PC is WIndows 10 and second PC is also Windows 10

Comment: Therefore perhaps Wifi is the explanation. Wifi can be slow. Can you try with another computer ?

Comment: @OlivierRogier yes I can but only on Monday. If the same problem exists then it is definitely WiFi. I will also connect the two PCs to the WiFi via a ethernet cable and see if theres any improvements. Thank you.

Comment: @David Great planning! And you will see the facts...

Comment: @OlivierRogier it was the Wifi!. Could you please put your comment as the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending of the connection, Wifi or cable RJ45, it may condition the response time, because Wifi is slower.

For example, RJ45 offers 100Mbps as actual ordinary standard, but Wifi can be slow as 6Mbps, and it requires more verification protocols, that sort of thing, like password and encryption checking.

And ping is higher.

And Window 10 is the most actual secure OS : even on RJ45 and on the same ADSL line, I noticed a little loss of performance compared to windows 7.

I have a little Windows 10 laptop on Wifi I never use but I found the connection very very slow (500k/s for real on a 16Mb line with my RJ45 desktop).

In addition to that, air transport may be reduced depending on the obstacle of objects and the distance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)